# Measurable sets with non computable measure

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am just curious if there are any measurable(in the sense of Lebesgue measure) sets with noncomputable measure just as there are noncomputable real numbers. I would be highly obliged for any clarifications

Comment: Does $[0, \alpha]$ where $\alpha$ is noncomputable work for you? Or are you looking for something else?

Comment: Meanwhile, while the measure of a "computably closed" set (= $\Pi^0_1$ class) need not be computable, it will always be *right c.e.*, so if you want a closed set of very noncomputable measure you will need to "cheat" a bit.

Comment: Thank you for your useful comments